# Passar inicio e fim de um vector pra função sort usando sobrecarga de método c++

Tags: c++, return, iterator

Quero acessar usando sobrecarga usando nó que é um objeto da classe base o método `getInicioVetor` e `getFimVetor` dentro da classe filha, gostaria de saber se existe um meio de fazer isso? Tentei assim só que não deu certo.

```
static bool ordenar(const TRegistro &f1, const TRegistro &f2){
   return f1.valor < f2.valor;
}

TRegistro getInicioVetor(){
    it = x.begin();
    return *it;
}

TRegistro getFimVetor(){
    it = x.end();
    return *it;
}


sort(no->getInicioVetor(), no->getFimVetor(), ordenar);
```